# How to increment through ArrayList and change its state?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I have a series of JCheckBox instances and I want to reset their state to unchecked using .setSelected(false), but I am unsure how to do this. I figured it was something like below, but it would not compile.

```
ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxList; //initialized in this manner earlier in code


    public class MyResetListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
         for(JCheckBox a : checkboxList){
             checkboxList.setSelected(false);
         }
    }
}
```

I tried this with a normal for loop as well, but was unsure how to access the ArrayList either way.

```
    public class MyResetListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
         for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
             checkboxList[i].setSelected(false);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? BTW the first example is totally fine, if you rename the loop variable to something else than 'a' ('a' is already defined to be an ActionEvent in the function parameter).

Answer (score 3):

It should just be:

```
for(JCheckBox b: checkboxList)
    b.setSelected(false);
```

I renamed `a` to `b` as `a` was already defined here - `ActionEvent a`.

`b` is the variable you're getting from the collection as you're iterating through it, thus you have to use that instead of `checkboxList`, which is the whole `ArrayList`.

Or:

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkboxList.size(); i++)
   checkboxList.get(i).setSelected(false);
```

Java classes (i.e. `ArrayList`) don't natively support the `[]` operation (though you do get extensions, and arrays are technically classes as well, and they do support it). `ArrayList` has a [`get` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) to get element from it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using array subscripts you must use methods, like `get()`

e.g.

```
checkboxList.get(i).setSelected(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correct for accessing an element in an ArrayList you can use the get method.

Your example will looks like:

```
     for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
         checkboxList.get(i).setSelected(false);
     }
```